# Redux or simple React to handle navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am very new to React and Redux and I am currently trying to wrap my head around how states are shared through the UI.

I have a pretty simple use case.

Picture a container with three columns:

1. A left Side Menu with four buttons
2. A central content section
3. A right container with some other content

When I click one of the four buttons I want three things to happen:

1. The class on the button is updated so it has borders
2. The class on the other buttons is updated so if they had been clicked before their border class is removed
3. The content in one part of the middle section is updated. This content requires data from the backend (Django Rest) to be fetched

Here are my questions:

1. Should I separate this interaction into a UI only concern and a Data driven one or handle both with a single state?
2. Because the buttons share a parent component but they do not with the central component, would I be better off using Redux if I do not want to define the state at the very top level of the Container?
3. Because I am new and Hooks seem to be the way to go I am trying to use hooks rather than classes, does it still make sense to separate components and containers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-router-dom library to achieve want you want.
for your left side menu you can create active class in css and then check for current route with `location.pathname` property of react-router-dom and if it is for that button, active class set for it.
and for your main section you can fetch data in useEffect hook.
I think it is good to separate data and UI but for buttons what I say is good.
and you can store data in redux for your main section.

Comment: Can you have several location instances? 
I will have another set of buttons in this left Menu that would update another part of the middle section. In that case it could be conflicting since, if I am not mistaken the pathname would be unique and shared by all these button sets.

Comment: @DataBrown yes `location.pathname` is based on url. With new information you add I think redux is better solution, or you can use url parameter for other set of buttons.